# How to ignore maxAttempts & send message to DLQ?

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit, dead-letter, poison-queue

I am using RabbitMQ. The consumer-api is using spring-cloud-steam.
Currently, as maxAttempts is 3, if the consumer fails to process the message, then it will be queued again. And this will happen 3 times. 
If 3rd time also message fails, then it will be sent to DLX->DLQ.

as per below image
[image: Existing Rabbitmq exchange-queue design]

Now I want to skip retrying if some specificException occurs in the listener side. How to skip this retry and send the message to DLX->DLQ directly for specificException?

Below is the configuration file.

```
spring:
  application:
    name: consumer-api
  cloud:
    stream:
      overrideCloudConnectors: true
      bindings:
        test_channel:
          destination: destinationName
          contentType: application/json
          group: groupName
          consumer:
            maxAttempts: 3
      rabbit:
        bindings:
          test_channel:
            consumer:
              durableSubscription: true
              exchangeType: direct
              bindingRoutingKey: do.test
              autoBindDlq: true
              deadLetterExchange: destinationName.dlx
              deadLetterQueueName: destinationName.dlx.groupName.dlq
              deadLetterRoutingKey: do.test
```

Below is the Listener code.

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class groupNameListener {

    @StreamListener(TEST_CHANNEL)
    public void doTest(Message<DoTestMessage> doTestMessage) {
        log.info("doTest message received: {}", doTestMessage);

        try {
            if ("someCondition".equals(doTestMessage.getPayload().getMessage())) {
                throw new SpecificException();
            } else {
                log.info("do normal work");
                throw new Exception(); //if something fails
            }
        } catch (SpecificException specificException) {
            log.error("Don't requeue but send to DLQ.... how  ????");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("Error in processing do test message");
            throw new AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException("Reject and Don't requeue exception");
            //this will requeue the message maximum 3 times. If maxAttempts has reached then will be send to DLX->DLQ
        }
    }
}
```

Could someone please help me? Please let me know if I'm making any mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The upcoming 2.1 release [adds the feature to specify which exceptions are, or are not, retryable](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/commit/de6aa8986b9803d0a1415464c7dacd54c2fba7b8).

2.1.0.M3 (milestone) is available now.

Exceptions that are not retryable will go directly to the DLQ.

Comment: Ok got it. Thank you for your reply :-)

Comment: With 2.0, you can provide a custom `RetryTemplate` that is wired with a suitably configured retry policy. https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Elmhurst.SR1/reference/htmlsingle/#_retry_template